# TensorFlow/TFLearn: ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64,) for Tensor u'target/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 10)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been trying to perform regression using [tflearn](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn) and my own dataset.

Using tflearn I have been trying to implement a convolutional network based off an [example](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_mnist.py) using the MNIST dataset. Instead of using the MNIST dataset I have tried replacing the training and test data with my own. My data is read in from a csv file and is a different shape to the MNIST data. I have 255 features which represent a 15*15 grid and a target value. In the example I replaced the lines 24-30 with (and included import numpy as np):

```
#read in train and test csv's where there are 255 features (15*15) and a target
csvTrain = np.genfromtxt('train.csv', delimiter=",")
X = np.array(csvTrain[:, :225]) #225, 15
Y = csvTrain[:,225]

csvTest = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=",")
testX = np.array(csvTest[:, :225])
testY = csvTest[:,225]

#reshape features for each instance in to 15*15, targets are just a single number
X = X.reshape([-1,15,15,1])
testX = testX.reshape([-1,15,15,1])

## Building convolutional network
network = input_data(shape=[None, 15, 15, 1], name='input')
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64,) for Tensor u'target/Y:0',
>   which has shape '(?, 10)'

I have tried various combinations and have seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238653/tensorflow-tflearn-valueerror-cannot-feed-value-of-shape-256-400-400-for-t) in stackoverflow but have not had success. The example in this page does not work for me and throws a similar error and I do not understand the answer provided or those provided by similar questions.

How do I use my own data?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Short answer

In the line 41 of the [MNIST example](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_mnist.py), you also have to change the output size 10 to 1 in `network = fully_connected(network, 10, activation='softmax')` to `network = fully_connected(network, 1, activation='linear')`. Note that you can remove the final softmax.

Looking at your code, it seems you have a target value `Y`, which means using the **L2 loss** with **`mean_square`** (you will find [here](http://tflearn.org/objectives/) all the losses available):

```
regression(network, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.01,
                 loss='mean_square', name='target')
```

Also, reshape Y and Y_test to have shape (batch_size, 1).

---

### Long answer: How to analyse the error and find the bug

Here is how to analyse the error:

- The error is `Cannot feed value ... for Tensor 'target/Y'`, which means it comes from the **feed_dict** argument Y.
- Again, according to the error, you try to feed an Y value `of shape (64,)` whereas the network expect a shape `(?, 10)`.

  - It expects  a shape (batch_size, 10), because originally it's a network for MNIST (10 classes)
- We now want to change the expected value of the network for Y.

  - in the code, we see that the last layer `fully_connected(network, 10, activation='softmax')` is returning an output of size 10
  - We change that to an output of size 1 without softmax: `fully_connected(network, 1, activation='linear')`

In the end, it was not a bug, but a wrong **model architecture**.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much for such a detailed answer.

Comment: Hope it works, and hope next time you will understand the (rather complex I must admit) error messages of Tensorflow

Comment: 2 years after, and @OlivierMoindrot you have no idea how thankful I am!