# Tensorflow reshaping error for 1d convolutional neural net

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I am building a 1d convolutional neural net for my own data (spectra) and am having an issue with tf.reshape. First I load in the data with pandas, and convert these to numpy arrays, composed of 708 training example spectra, each of length 2151,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv',header=None)
yTrue = data.ix[:,0].as_matrix()
data = data - data.mean()
data = data.ix[:,1:].as_matrix()
```

where I subtract the mean value in each column. So data is of dimensions 708 x 2151 here. I then create a network that starts with,

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
## define inputs
x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2151])
x_ = tf.reshape(x_, [-1,1,2151,1])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
```

which are inputs for my 1d convolutional neural net (with kernels with a width of 10, and 32 feature maps),

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([1, 10, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
```

I then build the rest of the network and then try to run ADAM on it,

```
cost_function = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(y_out - y_, 2))/(2 * samples_number) #L2 loss
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cost_function)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_out,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in range(20000):
    print(i)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x_: data, y_: yTrue})
```

However I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (708, 2151) for Tensor u'Reshape_26:0', 
which has shape '(?, 1, 2151, 1)'
```

I have looked at these answers: [TensorFlow/TFLearn: ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64,) for Tensor u'target/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 10)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433321/tensorflow-tflearn-valueerror-cannot-feed-value-of-shape-64-for-tensor-uta); [Tensorflow error using my own data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974231/tensorflow-error-using-my-own-data) which suggest that I need to be doing some reshaping before I pass my data to the network. However, I am not sure what this should be? Particularly since the following works on the first row of the data,

```
t = tf.constant(data[0])
tf.reshape(t,[1,1,2151,1])
```

Does anyone have any ideas here?

Best,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that feed_dict can replace any Tensor, and since you've changed x_ to reference the `reshape` op, that's the thing that it's trying to replace. It should work if you just use different Python variables to reference the placeholder and the reshape op:

```
x_placeholder_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2151])
x_ = tf.reshape(x_placeholder_, [-1,1,2151,1])
```

Then when feeding, use `x_placeholder_`:

```
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x_placeholder_: data, y_: yTrue})
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I change the code to the above I get the following error, InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_47' with dtype float
  [[Node: Placeholder_47 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]] -- Any ideas what this means? I thought that using feed_dict should mean this is fine...

Comment: Are you doing this inside a Jupyter notebook? It sounds like a whole bunch of placeholders are floating around. Try `tf.reset_default_graph()`?

Comment: I am. I tried the above, but unfortunately I am still having the same issue. Any more ideas? Sorry about this!

Comment: Is it `Placeholder_48` or something like `Placeholder_1`?

Comment: Hmm, could you try naming the placeholders by passing a `name=` argument?

Comment: When I do the following: x_placeholder_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2151],name="test") -- I get a Placeholder_1 error.

Comment: Is there another placeholder somewhere in your code, defined after the `tf.reset_default_graph`? If you name all of them, presumably the error will at least tell you which one.

Comment: Aha -- yes. Great thinking. It was a Placeholder for a probability of keeping a connection in a dropout layer, that I wasn't passing. Thank you so much for your help here. Really appreciate it. Best, Ben